# Python: listed dictionaries, replace certain values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension, python-2.6

How to replace values from specific keys in listed dictionaries? But replace should happen with a conditional (i.e. if they have 2 digits in the beginning). Preferably with list/dictionary comprehensions.

Example:

```
a_list = [{'key1': 'A picture 1', 'key2': 'location 1', 'key3': '20 title1'}, {'key1': 'A picture 2', 'key2': 'location 2', 'key3': '10 title2'}]
```

I want to remove the first two digits from the values of key3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do that using a dictionary comprehension within a list comprehension.

The dictionary comprehension rebuilds the dictionary, but alters the value if:

- key is `key3` AND
- first 2 chars of the string are digits

Alteration is taking the right part of the leading space.

```
a_list = [{'key1': 'A picture 1', 'key2': 'location 1', 'key3': '20 title1'}, {'key1': 'A picture 2', 'key2': 'location 2', 'key3': '10 title2'}]

a_new_list = [{k:v.partition(" ")[2] if (k=="key3" and v[:2].isdigit()) else v for k,v in d.items()} for d in a_list]

print(a_new_list)
```

result:

```
[{'key1': 'A picture 1', 'key2': 'location 1', 'key3': 'title1'}, {'key1': 'A picture 2', 'key2': 'location 2', 'key3': 'title2'}]
```

Note: Will also remove the first digits if there are more than 2 digits. The condition is broad and should be tuned to your needs.

EDIT: a pre Python 2.7 compliant alternative (dict comprehensions when did not exist):

```
a_new_list = [dict((k,v.partition(" ")[2] if (k=="key3" and v[:2].isdigit()) else v) for k,v in d.items()) for d in a_list]
```

Comment: That's great exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. I was thinking if we could do this with re.sub, but in any case I am going to adapt per my needs.

Comment: This works in python 2.7.X, however I am getting syntax error in python 2.6.X :(

Comment: that's because dict comprehensions were not available yet. edited for alternate solution, should work all right (gives the same results!!)

Answer (score 1):

There may be a way to do this with comprehensions, but in my opinion it is better to be a little more verbose to make the code's intention more clear:

```
import re

for d in a_list:
    for k in d:
        d[k] = re.sub(r'^\d\d', '', d[k]) if k == 'key3' else d[k]
```

Answer (score 0):

So I combined Jean-François Fabre's and Tom Lynch's answers, slightly altered regex patterned and came up with this:

```
import re

a_new_list = [{k: re.sub(r'^\d{2} ', '', d[k]) if k == "key3" else v for k, v in d.items()} for d in a_list]

print a_new_list
```